# How to check if asset was added from public/ dir in React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Is it possible to check if a file exists within the `/public/` directory?

I have a set of images that correspond to some objects. When available, I would like to display them using `<img>` tag. However not all of the objects have a corresponding image, in which case I would like to perform a REST request to our server.

I could create a list of files as part of build process, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

I am using `create-react-app` if it matters (if I understand correctly `fs` doesn't work in client-side React apps).

**EDIT**: I guess I should have been more exact in my question - I know client-side JS can't access this information (except through HTTP requests), I was just hoping something saves information (during build) about the files available in a way that is accessible to client-side Javascript... Maybe Webpack or some extension can do this?

Comment: public directory is on the server so react cannot help in checking it.. I think you should be checking with node..a get request can fetch you the data and if image url is retrieved than you can render it else show some default or whatever as per your design

Comment: Thanks! I have clarified the question... I was hoping there is a way to include this information at build time, for example by Webpack?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with your axios by setting relative path to the corresponding images folder. I have done this for getting a `json file`. You can try the same method for an `image file`, you may refer [these](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2006) examples

Note: if you have already set an axios instance with baseurl as a server in different domain, you will have to use the full path of the static file server where you deploy the web application.

```
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/assets/samplepic.png').then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

If the image is found the response will be 200 and if not, it will be 404.

Edit: Also, if the image file is present in assets folder inside src, you can do a `require`, get the path and do the above call with that path.

```
var SampleImagePath = require('./assets/samplepic.png');
axios.get(SampleImagePath).then(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should remember about client-server architecture of any web app. If you are using `create-react-app` you are serving your app via `webpack-dev-server`. So you should think about how you will host your files for production. Most common ways are:

- apache2 / nginx
- nodejs

but there is a lot of other ways depending on your stack.

With `webpack-dev-server` and in case you will use apache2 / nginx and if they would be configured to allow direct file access - it is possible to make direct requests to files. For example your files in public path so

```
class MyImage extends React.Component {
   constructor (props) {
       super(props);

       this.state = {
           isExist: null
       }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       fetch(MY_HOST + '/public/' + this.props.MY_IMAGE_NAME)
          .then(
              () => {
                  // request status is 200
                  this.setState({ isExist: true })
              },
              () => {
                  // request is failed
                  this.setState({ isExist: false })
              }
          );
   }

   render() {
       if (this.state.isExist === true) {
           return <img src={ MY_HOST + "/public/" + this.props.MY_IMAGE_NAME }/>
       }

       return <img src="/public/no-image.jpg"/>
   }
}
```